# modal.classList.remove('hidden') is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

modal.classList.remove('hidden') is not working.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');
const showBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');

for (let i = 0; i < showBtns.length; i++) {
  showBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    modal.classList.remove('hidden');
    console.log(modal.classList);
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="show-modal" value="Show">
<div class="modal hidden">This is .modal</div>
```

Comment: I've taken your code and pasted it into a Stack Snippet, adding a `class="modal hidden"` element and a `class="show-modal"` button. The code works. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem by editing the Snippet More about providing snippets [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 1):

Your script works nicely removing class `hidden` after the first click. But if you want to show the hidden element again after a second click you have to use `toggle` instead of `remove` to restore the .hidden class, hiding it again.

See [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

EDIT: In my example, I also replace the button's value according to the class.  See the line
 `showBtns[i].value  = (modal.classList.contains('hidden')) ? "Show" : "Hide";`

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');
const showBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.show-modal');

for (let i = 0; i < showBtns.length; i++) {
  showBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    modal.classList.toggle('hidden');
    showBtns[i].value  = (modal.classList.contains('hidden')) ? "Show" : "Hide";
    console.log(modal.classList);
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="show-modal" value="Show">
<div class="modal hidden">This is .modal</div>
```